# Sending data back to a certain UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

In my app I have a tableview filled with conversations meaning each cell has a different persons name.  When i select a cell i perform a segue to another viewcontroller which has a giant UITextView displaying the message from that person's name in the cell.  On this view I also have a reply button in the right hand corner and when you press it, it segues to another viewcontroller with an editable uitextview in which you can create a reply and send it.

How do i send this reply back to the original tableviewcell so that when you go back to the original tableview and click on that same conversation, you will see your reply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tableview you should be displaying an array of a certain custom data object, say `Conversation`. In your `Conversation` object you could have a property `NSString *latestMessage`. So, when you navigate to the conversation and reply to the previous message, you update the `latestMessage` property to be your reply, which updates the `Conversation` object itself. Then, when you navigate back to the tableview it should re-display all of the `Conversation` objects in your array, which displays the updated `Conversation`. The label on the cell should be set to the `latestMessage` object of the `Conversation` instance.